# Protected Nested Struct Cannot Be Used As Return Type in Derived Outer Class?

Tags: c++, class, nested, inner-classes

I have the following class (simplified)

**Base Class - ExchangeGatewayUDSHandler.h**

```
    class ExchangeGatewayUDSHandler : public Instrument::IInstrumentListener
    {
    public:

        explicit ExchangeGatewayUDSHandler(const EGUDSConfig& config);
        virtual ~ExchangeGatewayUDSHandler();

        void ProcessEnqueue(UDSRequest& udsRequest);

    protected:

        struct UDSValidityInfo
        {
        public:
            UDSValidityInfo() = default;

            void SetValidity(const bool validity) { isValid_ = validity; }
            void SetReason(const char* reason) { reason_ = reason; }
            inline const std::string GetReason() const { return reason_; }
            inline const bool GetValidity() const { return isValid_; }

        private:
            bool isValid_;
            std::string reason_;
        };

        virtual UDSValidityInfo UDSRequestIsValid(const UDSRequest& udsReq) { return {}; }
   };
```

As you can see, `UDSValidityInfo` is a nested struct. It will only ever be created within `ExchangeGatewayUDSHandler` and all its derived classes. The only issue is, that for some reason, in the CPP file of the derived class `ExchangeGatewayICEUDSHandler` I cannot return `UDSValidityInfo`.

**Derived Class - ExchangeGatewayICEUDSHandler.h**

```
    class ICEGatewayUDSHandler: public ExchangeGatewayUDSHandler
    {
    public:

        ICEGatewayUDSHandler(const ExchangeGatewayUDSHandlerConfig& config);

    protected:

        virtual UDSValidityInfo UDSRequestIsValid(const UDSRequest& udsReq) override; // No error

    };
```

**Derived Class - ExchangeGatewayICEUDSHandler.cpp**

```
    ICEGatewayUDSHandler::ICEGatewayUDSHandler(const ExchangeGatewayUDSHandlerConfig& config)
        :   ExchangeGatewayUDSHandler(config) {};

    // Error in return type
    UDSValidityInfo ICEGatewayUDSHandler::UDSRequestIsValid(const UDSRequest& udsReq) 
    {
        UDSValidityInfo validityObject{}; // No error creating the struct here.
        validityObject.SetValidity(true);

        if (udsReq.legs_.empty())
        {
            validityObject.SetReason("The UDS contains no legs.");
            validityObject.SetValidity(false);
        }

        return validityObject;
    }
```

Visual Studio 19 says the error is:

> Identifier "UDSValidityInfo" is unidentified

I also get an error in the type of the function (`virtual UDSValidityInfo UDSRequestIsValid(const UDSRequest& udsReq) override;`), even though there is no error for this function in the .h file (where it is declared), saying the two function are incompatible.

I'm not sure why this is the case. When I make the struct static, the problem goes away, but I think this is cheating.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .cpp files, which are outside of the `ExchangeGatewayUDSHandler` and `ICEGatewayUDSHandler` class declarations, you need to qualify `UDSValidityInfo` in a method return value so the compiler knows where to look for that type, as it has not seen the `ExchangeGatewayUDSHandler::` or `ICEGatewayUDSHandler::` qualifiers yet, eg:

```cpp
ExchangeGatewayUDSHandler::UDSValidityInfo ICEGatewayUDSHandler::UDSRequestIsValid(const UDSRequest& udsReq) 
{
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `auto` with a trailing return type, so that the compiler will see the `ExchangeGatewayUDSHandler::` or `ICEGatewayUDSHandler::` qualifier before it sees the `UDSValidityInfo` type, and thus will know the correct scope to look in for it, eg:

```cpp
auto ICEGatewayUDSHandler::UDSRequestIsValid(const UDSRequest& udsReq) -> UDSValidityInfo
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: So pretty much I need to use the scope-resolution operator on the base class (ExchangeGatewayUDSHandler) to instruct the compiler to look in that class for this struct. Strange how it can't find it otherwise. I mean, I don't need to qualify a function declared in a base class in my derived class. So why the difference?

The second trick is also really neat. Thanks so much.

Comment: Yes, you need to qualify the return type on a method *definition* (not on the *declaration*), because at the time the compiler is parsing the *definition*, it parses the return type first and hasn't yet parsed the class name that the returning method belongs to. So you have to help the compiler a little. When you declare a method override in a derived class, the compiler knows the context that *declaration* is in, so less qualification is needed.  Context is important.

Comment: Damn... Learning more every day. Thanks Remy.